# Bash Ques: How can I do this -> Check if any of the string from JSON/Cat file matches from the variable string then do something

Tags: bash, shell, ssl, cryptography

I have a list of weak ciphers which is not safe. **Weak cipher**:

```
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

I have a tool result that tells what hashes does a website SSL supports, something like this **Result ciper**:

```
 The server accepted the following 13 cipher suites:
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384                   256                      
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256                   256                      
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                      256                      
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256                   128                      
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256                   128                      
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA                      128                      
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256       256       ECDH: X25519 (253 bits)
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384             256       ECDH: prime256v1 (256 bits)
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384             256       ECDH: prime256v1 (256 bits)
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                256       ECDH: prime256v1 (256 bits)
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256             128       ECDH: prime256v1 (256 bits)
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256             128       ECDH: prime256v1 (256 bits)
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA                128       ECDH: prime256v1 (256 bits)
```

I want to write a `bash` command which can check if any cipher is from the above list then it is not safe.

> ```
> if any result cipher matches from any weak cipher; then
> echo "Weak cipher: $cipher_name1, Weak cipher: $cipher_name2"
> else
> echo "Good Cipher"
> ```

Comment: Please add your desired output for exact that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```sh
cat test_data.txt | tail +2 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I {} bash -c 'if [[ $WEAK_CIPHERS == *"{}"* ]]; then echo Weak cipher: {}; fi'
```

Replace the `cat test_data.txt` with the command that outputs the example you gave.

Make sure you define the WEAK_CIPHERS var with:

```sh
export WEAK_CIPHERS='ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384'
```